# How to replace non-zero elements randomly with zero?

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix including `1` and `0` elements like below which is used as a network adjacency matrix.

```
A =

    0     1     1     1
    1     1     0     1
    1     1     0     1
    1     1     1     0
```

I want to simulate an attack on the network, so I must replace some specific percent of `1` elements randomly with `0`. How can I do this in MATLAB?

I know how to replace a percentage of elements randomly with zeros, but I must be sure that the element that is replaced randomly, is one of the `1` elements of matrix not zeros.

Comment: Do you want the probability that a 1 element is replaced to be `percentage`/100 independent of whether or not another has been replaced. Or do you want `percentage` 1 elements to be replaced at random?

Comment: @horchler Hey, that's good point

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to change each `1` with a certain probability:

```
p = 0.1%; % desired probability of change

A_ones = find(A); % linear index of ones in A
A_ones_change = A_ones(rand(size(A_ones))<=p); % entries to be changed
A(A_ones_change) = 0; % apply changes in those entries
```

If you want to randomly change a *fixed* fraction of the `1` entries:

```
f = 0.1; % desired fraction

A_ones = find(A);
n = round(f*length(A_ones));
A_ones_change = randsample(A_ones,n);
A(A_ones_change) = 0;
```

Note that in this case the resulting fraction may be different to that intended, because of the need to round to an integer number of entries.

Answer (score 3):

@horchler's point is a good one. However, if we keep it simple, then you can just multiple your input matrix to a mask matrix.

```
>> a1=randint(5,5,[0 1]) #before replacing 1->0

a1 =

     1     1     1     0     1
     0     1     1     1     0
     0     1     0     0     1
     0     0     1     0     1
     1     0     1     0     1

>> a2=random('unif',0,1,5,5) #Assuming frequency distribution is uniform ('unif')

a2 =

    0.7889    0.3200    0.2679    0.8392    0.6299
    0.4387    0.9601    0.4399    0.6288    0.3705
    0.4983    0.7266    0.9334    0.1338    0.5751
    0.2140    0.4120    0.6833    0.2071    0.4514
    0.6435    0.7446    0.2126    0.6072    0.0439

>> a1.*(a2>0.1) #And the replacement prob. is 0.1

ans =

     1     1     1     0     1
     0     1     1     1     0
     0     1     0     0     1
     0     0     1     0     1
     1     0     1     0     0
```

And other trick can be added to the mask matrix (a2). Such as a different freq. distribution, or a structure (e.g. once a cell is replaced, the adjacent cells become less likely to be replaced and so on.)
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The function find is your friend:

```
indices = find(A);
```

This will return an array of the  indices of 1 elements in your matrix A and you can use your method of replacing a percent of elements with zero on a subset of this array. Then,

```
A(subsetIndices) = 0;
```

will replace the remaining indices of A with zero.